# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE unicorns
ALTER COLUMN last_valuation_upd TYPE numeric USING (last_valuation_upd::numeric);
```

It shows this error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "" SQL state: 22P02

Comment: `alter table unicorns alter column last_valuation_upd type numeric using (nullif(last_valuation_upd,'')::numeric);`

Comment: To be clear `select ''::numeric; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""` is the issue. An empty string is invalid for a numeric types e.g. `integer`, `float`, `numeric`.

Comment: Nice it worked perferctly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you had the column as text before and now changing it to numeric. Probably the quotes and commas (if any) existing in the table can be a problem and may need to be removed.